# In django queryset filter, how to check if at least one key in json field has non empty value?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-jsonfield

```
class Library(models.model):
    book = JSONField(default=[], blank=True, null=True)
```

possible structure of 'book' is {'title':'' ,'no_of_pages': '', 'author_name': '', 'color': '', edition: ''}

I am trying to write a django query that returns only records where book has at least one key with non empty value ( i.e either *title* or *no_of_pages* or *author_name* or *color* or *edition* has some value)

one possible solution to this is something like:

```
Author.objects.filter(
    ~Q(book__title='') |
    ~Q(book__no_of_pages='') | 
    ~Q(book__author_name='') |
    ~Q(book__color='') |
    ~Q(book__edition='')
)
```

is there any better way to do this ? There may be case where book can have some additional keys in future like *publisher* or *availabilty*

How can I perform this filter without having to mention the specific keys of the field ( just check at least one key with some value) ? or any shorter method to write this query with all the keys mentioned ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Author.objects.filter(book__has_any_keys=['title', 'no_of_pages', 'author_name', 'color'])
```

try this as specified in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#std:fieldlookup-hstorefield.has_any_keys), if this works for you.

Comment: above solution checks only keys in the table but does not ensure their values. I want to check if atleast one value is specified for any key. 

for e.g If have two rows
1.  {{'title': 'Example' ,'no_of_pages': '', 'author_name': '', 'color': '', edition: ''} 
2. {'title':'' ,'no_of_pages': '', 'author_name': '', 'color': '', edition: ''}
Filter should return only first one as title has some value.

Answer (score 0):

The list of authors where the book is not the empty dict.

```
Author.objects.filter(~Q(book__exact={}))
```